# How can I remove the arrows that appear when making a table contenteditable

Tags: html

I **edited** the image to make my question more clear

[image]

The Arrows appear when I click in a cell to edit it

(I use firefox)

```html
<table contenteditable=""><tr><td>test</td><td>→</td><td>test</td></tr><tr><td>test</td><td>→</td><td>test</td></tr><tr><td>test</td><td>→</td><td>test</td></tr><tr><td>test</td><td>→</td><td>test</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Don't make the table editable, but a cell

Comment: And if others have the same problem? or is my question a duplicate?

Comment: It is not a duplicate, just fairly obvious

Comment: I changed the image but for some reason I can't see any image now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">test</td>
    <td>→</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">test</td>
    <td>→</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">test</td>
    <td>→</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">test</td>
    <td>→</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I already commented this 20 minutes ago.  It is the obvious answer. At least format and comment the answer. I made you a snippet